# Power BI - Getting data from sources with no direct API

Tags: api, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am working on designing a Power BI dashboard and would require some insights on the source of data. My source of financial data comprises of Kyriba, Bloomberg and ClearWater Analytics. However, no API exists for either of these in Power BI. What’s the best way to pull data from these sources into PowerBI? Manual generation of excel always? Need assistance in understanding the best way to automate this process? Thank You!

Comment: Scrape it, and import it.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately or maybe fortunately these sites are highly secured, so at the moment there is no connector to these companies' data. But I am quite sure that there are some automatic extraction in csv files or even excel files. Once you have these files you can do everything you want in your Power BI.

Maybe you can contact your IT to check if there is any ftp channel possible to automate the import.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Nelson for the response. Appreciate it.